# Unable to select the Linux 2 AMI on AWS in launch configuration

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I am unable to filter the "Amazon Linux 2" AMI while creating the launch configuration under the AMI drop down menu.  I can see My AMI, Marketplace in the drop down. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this is a good question, same doubt for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it by searching with **AMI id**.

Actually the AMI name for amazon linux 2 is - "amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20200917.0-x86_64-gp2"
You can find the name and id from an already running instance. (ami id differs by region)

Sorry for being late, but I hope it helps.